# Unable to create a constant value of type... + cross context join?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to make a cross context query and got completely lost. I have an "airport" and a "plane" entity class (different contexts). All airports have an Id and the planes have a "Airport_Id" foreign key, which indicates where they are going. My query is about getting the busiest airports (where the most planes go to).

I made two queries to make cross context join work (no idea if this works). After getting rid of the context error, I got a new one: unable to create a constant value of type 'Planes.Data.Plane'. I've spent a lot of time to find a solution. Somewhere I've found .AsEnumerable() but it did nothing (with the error). I'm very grateful for any help, I'm completely stuck and confused. I've never used lambda linq before, it is not requirement but this was the only way to insert the ".AsEnumerable()".

```
        public IList<PlanesPerAirport> GetBusiestAirports()
           {
        var q = (from ap in this.planeRepo.GetAll()
                 select ap).ToList();

        var q2 = this.airportRepo.GetAll().
                  Join(q,
                  x => x.Id,
                  y => y.Airport_Id,
                  (x, y) => new {
                      AirportId = x.Id,
                      PlaneId = y.Airport_Id,
                  }).AsEnumerable().
                  GroupBy(z => z.AirportId).
                  //OrderBy(z => z.Count). -ERROR- the type arguments for method IEnumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumenrable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
                  Select(z =>
                  new PlanesPerAirport
                  {
                      Id = z.Key,
                      //Count = z.Count, -ERROR- cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'int'
                  });

        return q2.ToList();  // -ERROR- "unable to create a constant value of type 'Planes.Data.Plane' Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context
    }

public class PlanesPerAirport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add text of errors?

Comment: I do anything for help...

Comment: To get rid of the exception (unable to create a constant value...), `q` should be a list of Plane *id* values (not planes). Then in the second query use `Contains`.

Comment: Also, why are these entities in different contexts? Are they in different databases?

Comment: If they're not in different databases you can save yourself an awful lot of trouble by not using different contexts.

Comment: I rewrote my whole code to make this possible, so problem solved, query works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var q2 = this.airportRepo.GetAll().
                  Join(q,
                  x => x.Id,
                  y => y.Airport_Id,
                  (x, y) => new {
                      AirportId = x.Id,
                      PlaneId = y.Airport_Id,
                  })
                  .GroupBy(z => z.AirportId, (x,y)=> new PlanesPerAirport
                  {
                      Id = x,
                      Count = y.Count()
                  }) 
                  .OrderBy(z => z.Count);
```

Comment: Actually, *you* should try this before posting. Then, if it works (it doesn't), you could post it as an answer instead of a suggestion. "Try this" answers aren't really valuable. Working code with an explanation is.

Comment: Ty vm. It actually worked after Arnold's advice. I can't believe I crashed this code about 100 times in the past 3 hours and now runs:)

Comment: Did this particular answer work though? I don't think it did.

Comment: @ Gert Arnold May you explain why you think that this code don't work?

Comment: You are right it does not sadly. I got excited because it run and I got back something but it is null. Anyway this answer helped me a lot to understand lambda linq, so thank you for that but I take away the acceptence not to confuse others.

Comment: @RomaRuzich Because the exeception is caused by `Join(q, ...`.

Comment: Ops, I understand. Problem with `q`. I tested it on `IEnumerable` and overlooked this problem. Sorry.

Comment: As @ Gert Arnold wrote it is necessary to replace `Join` into `Where` with filter by `Id.Contains....`. Thanks, @ Gert Arnold